# Как с помощью js управлять backround inputa

Tags: javascript, css

Мне нужно в инпуте у которого класс .time-spending-input менять background-image когда в нём появляется текст. Как

```
let allInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function removeDone(input){
       for(const input of allInput){
        if(input.value ==" "){
            form.querySelectorAll(".time-spending-input").style.backgroundImage = "url(image/check.svg)";
        }
    }
}

removeDone(input)
```

Comment: Если `.time-spending-input` один, то используйте `document.querySelector`, т.к. `document.querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию и надо проходиться по ней циклом, что бы что от поменять в элементах

Comment: @SwaD .time-spending-input  их  4

Comment: Тогда ваш код должен выглядеть как то так: `.querySelectorAll(".time-spending-input").forEach(item => item.style.backgroundImage = "url(image/check.svg)")`

Answer (score 3):

> Мне нужно в инпуте у которого класс .time-spending-input менять background-image **когда в нём появляется текст**

```css
.time-spending-input{width: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, green, blue)}

.time-spending-input::placeholder{ opacity: 1;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow, red)}
```

```html
<input placeholder='а обязательно JavaScript юзать? может и так сойдёт? :3'
class='time-spending-input'>
```